# What's the advantage of mysqli_stmt_bind_result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm converting my php / mySQL code to use prepared statements.
I can see the value (security, etc) of preparing SQL or DML and binding parameters. But my queries specify the fields in the select list by name and I use the associative array to access them.

Or, is to help in cases like this one where I have had to make an assumption about the index in the result array?

```
$listquery = "SELECT {$tables["result"]}.time, " .
             "       HOUR({$tables["result"]}.time), " .    // [1]
             "       MINUTE({$tables["result"]}.time), " .  // [2]
             "       SECOND({$tables["result"]}.time), " .  // [3]
             "       {$tables["rider"]}.id, {$tables["rider"]}.gender, " .
             "       {$tables["rider"]}.first, {$tables["rider"]}.last, " .
             "       {$tables["result"]}.dnf, " .
             "       {$tables["race"]}.courseid " .
             "  FROM {$tables["race"]}, {$tables["result"]}, {$tables["rider"]} " .
             " WHERE {$tables["race"]}.raceid = {$tables["result"]}.raceid " .
             "   AND {$tables["result"]}.riderid = {$tables["rider"]}.id" .
             "   AND {$tables["race"]}.raceid = ? " .
          " ORDER BY {$tables["result"]}.dnf, {$tables["result"]}.time ASC ";
```

Comment: I'd be happier if this question had _some_ qualifiers like `verifiable`, `meaningful`, `conceptual` to decrease the likelihood of answers like "In this particular case bind_result is 0.000000345 ± 1.2 ns  faster on my (not further specified) machine" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `MYSQLND` driver, you can either use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` to get the results of a prepared query. There's no particular benefit to either approach.

If you don't have the `MYSQLND` driver, the only way to get the results of a `SELECT` query is with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`.

Your use of an associative array to specify the table names is not really relevant. You're still using a placeholder in `AND {$tables["race"]}.raceid = ?`, so you need to prepare the query.

Comment: Sorry, the comment about binding the table identifier was by me, not the OP. I was refering to "Putting variables into the SQL allows SQL injection. You should use mysql_stmt_bind_param to fix that" because there simply wasn't anything _more_ the OP could have done with mysql prepared statements + parameters ;-)

Comment: I am preparing the query and binding a param (or will be when I finish converting).  But I am **not** using mysqli_stmt_bind_result for retrieving the selected columns

Comment: @BryanT If you have the MYSQLND driver, that's fine.

Comment: @VolkerK I am (or will be) binding the parameters. That was the purpose of my rewrite - I want to avoid the injection issue. (Although I am already using the sanitize methods.)

Comment: "Although I am already using the sanitize methods" - You're using both? But not on the same parameter I hope. And escape_string isn't exactly tailor made for sanitizing identifiers. The postgresql extension e.g. offers a [function to do exactly that](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php), but the mysql extensions don't.

Comment: @BryanT I don't understand what that has to do with your question, which is about `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`. There's no SQL-injection issue when getting results from a query, so it doesn't matter which method you use.

Comment: @VolkerK  - no, I'm not using both. I meant that my first solution to the injection issue was to sanitize the user input. Now I am using the prepare and bind technique.

Comment: @Barmer - I used the bind method because of the injection issue. In the PHP man pages the bind_result was also shown. I know I don't have to use both, and that accessing results is not a security problem. I just wanted to know what the advantage, if any, of bind result was. I think that's been answered.